# X has 8 features, but RandomForestRegressor is expecting 67 features as input

Tags: python, prediction

I want to build a House Price Prediction app. The content has features where user can enter their inputs, then a predictive model will predict the price and display it to the user. I am using a dataset from Kaggle to do the prediction. When I run the code, it shows an error message that says

> X has 8 features, but RandomForestRegressor is expecting 67 features as input.

Below is the code. `Xy` contains the data from Kaggle and `df` is the user input. `Xy` is the train set and `df` is the test. `Xy` has 8 variables including the target. `df` will only retrieve 7 inputs (so it will have 7 variables because there's no target variables received from user).

```py
# Assign to X for input features and Y for target
X = Xy.drop('Price', axis=1)
Y = Xy['Price'].values

# Build Regression Model
model = RandomForestRegressor()
model.fit(X, Y)

df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Location', 'Furnishing', 'Property_Type_Supergroup', 'Size_Type'])
# Apply Model to Make Prediction
prediction = model.predict(df)
```

I tried to search the solutions online but nothing works for my code. Hope someone can help.

Comment: I'm afraid you are passing variables in in wrong way. you fit the model by `X` & `Y` but you used trained model to predict on `df` !! it doesn't make a sense due to mismatching the shape of data.

Comment: I  see. I refer to this article [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-connect-model-input-data-with-predictions-for-machine-learning/) , that's why I don't know which part I make the mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

**The X dataframes need to have the same amount of features**

I had this issue and found that I wasn't consistent with the amount of features I put into: `model.predict(X_predict)` and `model.fit(X_train, y_train)`. In my case X_predict had less features than X_train.

You can check so all the X dataframes you pass to predict and fit has the same features (columns) by printing:

```
print("X_predict", X_predict.columns)
print("X_train", X_train.columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like possibly you're fitting the model on a data frame of 67 features.  The data frame that you call fit on needs to be the same as the data frame you call predict on (at least in terms of features).

Answer (score 0):

> "X has 8 features, but RandomForestRegressor is expecting 67 features as input."

I assumed that this is the standard [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data) you used, and after unzipping and loading it has the following files:

```
sample_submission.csv
test.csv
data_description.txt
train.csv
```

if you check the shape of train.csv and test.csv:

```py
train = pd.read_csv('./house_prices/train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('./house_prices/test.csv')
print(f'Train shape : {train.shape}')
print(f'Test shape : {test.shape}')
#Train shape : (1460, 81)
#Test shape : (1459, 80)
```

That shows you deleted or dropped some column/features/attributes and reduced them from `81` to `67`, so no problem till now. The problem is once you converted the categorical variables into numeric variables using `pd.get_dummies()` in the data *pre-processing* stage then *split data* into `x_train` & `y_train` using **same** `df` to `fit()` your model. Finally, you predict on `x_test` via `y_pred = model.predict(x_test)`. Otherwise, the shape of `df` does not match `X` (one has 8 columns, the other has 67 columns in your case)!!

So I suggest first the `df` should be splitted:

```py
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

#  Chossing features for predicting the target variable
x = df

# Data split on df
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2 , random_state=42)

# Apply RandomForestRegressor
model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=300, max_depth=13, random_state=0)
model.fit(x_train,y_train)

# Predicting the data using the model
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)

# Evaluating the model 
print(metrics.r2_score(y_test,y_pred))
```

I included following posts for your reference:

- [post1](https://medium.com/hackerdawn/house-prices-prediction-using-random-forest-aa8722347276)
- [post2](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/predicting-house-price-with-random-forest-regressor-6e9a7c7f75dd)
- [post3](https://towardsdatascience.com/predicting-housing-prices-using-a-scikit-learns-random-forest-model-e736b59d56c5)